# Using TFS 2015 Power Tools for Workspace Templates

Tags: tfs, tfs-power-tools

Has anyone managed to use the Create Workspace from Template with a local path value replacement working?
I have set the local folder to C:\ROOT\ and then entered a folder name in the Local Path field when creating a workspace but it always creates the workspace with C:\root\ and doesn't replace using the path.  The Source Control Folder path does accept ROOT and the Branch Path replaces this ok.
Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you create template from original template, set the local folder to `Z:\\ROOT\xx`, check the screenshot below:

[image]

When create workspace from new created template, set local path to `e:\ws\` (example), check the screenshot below:

[image]

Check the new created workspace setting:

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. Although you have just spelled out to me the instructions again I just realised while ROOT is replaced on a Server path, Z:\\ROOT is replaced on a local path.  It was the Z drive part I was excluding in my trials previously which I have changed to get this working now.  Thanks again!